# Variadic class template and inheritance - default compiler generated constructor

Tags: c++, c++17

How come the below code works w/ just the default compiler generated constructor?
I would expect it for POD but the struct below is probably not a POD so it must be something else.

```
template <typename ... T>
struct C : T ... {
   using T::operator()...;
};

// template class guidance feature of C++17
template <typename ... T>
C(T...) -> C<T...>;

int main(){
   C c { []{}, [](int){} };
   c(3);
}
```

This question comes as a follow up to Jason's Turner C++ weekly ep 49/50 where he defined a variadic constructor with `std::forward<T>(t)...`

Comment: "POD" isn't really a thing in C++ anymore.

Comment: `C` is a C++17 aggregate.

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware of this new C++17.

Comment: @Kerrek SB not true,  std::is_pod<C>() is still at play. But pod  assumes many things,  to be trivial at first.. that's not a trivial class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no constructors at play here. This code works due to a confluence of three features new in C++17:

1. Template parameter deduction for constructors ([P0091](http://wg21.link/p0091)).
2. Extending aggregate initialization ([P0017](http://wg21.link/p0017))
3. Modernizing using-declarations ([P0195](http://wg21.link/p0195)).

What happens in this line:

```
C c { []{}, [](int){} };
```

is that first, we use template parameter deduction (1) to deduce that `c` is really of type `C<__lambda1, __lambda2>`. This is done through the use of your *deduction guide*.

Next, since `C<__lambda1, __lambda2>` is an aggregate (due to (2)'s relaxation of base class restrictions - you are correct that is not considered an aggregate in C++11/14), we can use *aggregate-initialization* to initialize it. We do *not* use a constructor. The way aggregate initialization now works with base classes is that we just have to initializes the bases left-to-right. So the first expression (`[]{}`) is used to initialize the first base class (`__lambda1`) and the second expression (`[](int){}`) is used to initialize the second base class (`__lambda2`).

Lastly, the call `c(3)` works because (3) allowed you to simply write

```
using T::operator()...;
```

which brings in both lambdas' call operators into the scope of `C`, where overload resolution can work as expected. The result is that we call `__lambda2`'s call operator, which does nothing.

Comment: thanks. If I'd have a member in C, say int i; this whole thing would break, right? there is no way I can initialize B... and also C's int i; member. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I think that'd be, e.g., `C c { []{}, [](int){}, 1 };`. You initialise aggregate members after the bases in the initialiser. See "Scope" in [P0017r1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0017r1.html)